# To optimise performance, should I store web data as CSV or JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, csv, request

I'm working with a dataset that's relatively large for web users, especially smartphone users. I'm worried about performance. Which is a bigger problem for users?

1. Forcing the client's browser to fetch/request a large data file (`JSON`).
2. Forcing the client's browser to reformat a smaller file (`CSV`) into a larger file (`JSON`) so it can be used.

When I compile the data as `JSON`, it's about **570KB** – far larger than I would normally use. And that's stripped right down (e.g. I've reduced the keys to a single character each).

When I compile the data as `CSV`, it's about **220KB**. However, I then need the browser to reformat it into `JSON` format anyway.

Here's a tiny example. A `CSV` file:

```
"year","birth","101","102","103","104","105"
1981,"Australia",5972,1099,573,747,667
1981,"China",141,4,3,2,2
1981,"India",139,5,4,6,2
1981,"Indonesia",371,9,14,5,6
1981,"Malaysia",838,72,42,11,14
```

... compared with the same data as `JSON`:

```
[{"year":1981,"birth":"Australia","101":5972,"102":1099,"103":573,"104":747,"105":667},
{year":1981,"birth":"China","101":141,"102":4,"103":3,"104":2,"105":2},
{year":1981,"birth":"India","101":139,"102":5,"103":4,"104":6,"105":2},
{year":1981,"birth":"Indonesia","101":371,"102":9,"103":14,"104":5,"105":6},
{year":1981,"birth":"Malaysia","101":838,"102":72,"103":42,"104":11,"105":14}]
```

TLDR: What's more important for performance: (1) minimising the size of data files, or (2) minimising the amount of data processing the browser must do?

Comment: The network request is going to be asynchronous, so your user won't lose interactivity with the page if it takes a tiny bit more time. The csv parsing, on the other hand, will block interactivity if it is slow, assuming you are not using a service worker. Therefore the json is preferable from a user's perspective, assuming a worst case scenario. However, in practice, I doubt either solution is going to lead to a perceptible slow-down relative to the other.

Comment: @M-N You could do the CSV parsing in a web-worker and return the materialized data to the web-page via a message. That said, I don't recommend processing CSV data in JavaScript simply because JavaScript does not have (widely supported) string and stream processing support (e.g. as JavaScript strings are immutable and there's no mutable string builder, building CSV strings and performing lots of `string.split` calls will waste memor with excessive string copies and allocations).

Comment: Feedback on why the question was down-voted would be appreciated.

Comment: I’d like to add that V8 switches off its optimising compiler when running on some mobile devices. That’s a reason to consider avoiding a lot of data processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preface:

I'd argue that what you're wanting to do is a kind of premature microoptimization ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization ), this is because most webservers will GZip HTTP responses anyway, so as far as actual transferred data is concerned both the CSV and expanded JSON representations will have roughly the same GZip size because they have the same Information Entropy.

Also, I recommend reading this article from Google (dated June 2019): https://v8.dev/blog/cost-of-javascript-2019 - in short: JavaScript is *cheap* and you only need to worry about optimization on mobile devices, not desktops/laptops.

### Anyway:

There are a few other alternatives besides CSV and JSON Objects.

### JSON Arrays:

One option, which is probably the best of both worlds, is using JSON arrays, like so:

```
[
 [ "year","birth","101","102","103","104","105" ],
 [ 1981,"Australia",5972,1099,573,747,667 ],
 [ 1981,"China",141,4,3,2,2 ],
 [ 1981,"India",139,5,4,6,2 ],
 [ 1981,"Indonesia",371,9,14,5,6 ],
 [ 1981,"Malaysia",838,72,42,11,14 ]
]
```

You can use named `const` array indexes to access each data member:

```
const Idx = {
    YEAR: 0,
    BIRTH: 1,
    _101: 2,
    _102: 3,
    _104: 4,
    // etc
};

var data = JSON.parse( text ); // the array from above

for( var i = 1; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    var row = data[i];

    console.log( "Year: %d, Birth: %s", row[Idx.YEAR], row[Idx.BIRTH] );
}
```

You could also have your own materialization function to convert each row into a strongly-typed object:

```
function Item( row ) {
    this.year = row[Idx.YEAR];
    this.birth = row[Idx.BIRTH];
}

var data = JSON.parse( text ); // the array from above

var items = data.map( row => new Item( row ) );
```

### Array of constructor calls

Another alternative to representing each record as an array within a parent array is to represent each record as a constructor call - however this will not work with `JSON.parse` - you must either use `eval()` (**NOT RECOMMENDED**), render data directly within a web-page inside your server-side generation script, or have the client load it into a `<script>` element (this is how JSONP works, but is dangerous).

I use this approach myself when rendering data to a webpage for consumption by third-party data-visualization components like D3 or various other charting libraries:

```
function Item( year, birth, _101, _102, _103, _104, _105 ) {
    this.year = year;
    this.birth = birth;
    this._101 = _101;
    this._102 = etc...
}

data = [
    new Item( 1981,"Australia",5972,1099,573,747,667 ),
    new Item( 1981,"China",141,4,3,2,2 ),
    new Item( 1981,"India",139,5,4,6,2 ),
    new Item( 1981,"Malaysia",838,72,42,11,14 ),
    // etc
];

renderChart( data );
```

I use this approach when I need to perform client-side transformation of data and I don't want to render two copies of the data in different formats to the response, for example. But as I said, this technique does not work with `JSON.parse` because json must be just static data and not a constructor call.

Comment: Thanks @Dai. The JSON array is a good idea, though I wonder whether the materialisation function would itself affect performance, given how many times I would need to call it. I'm also considering the convenience for me (the programmer). One of the beauty's of JSON is the code is easily understood!

Comment: @Markus The only way to see if there will be a performance problem will by profiling and benchmarking **for your situation**. I don't know what you're planning on doing with the data so I can't _yet_ speculate what perf will be like.

Comment: I see that my answer has been downvoted (and someone else upvoted it). Please respond in a comment reply why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Jai, the data feeds an interactive viz (maps linked to charts). I call on the data whenever the user interacts with viz (e.g. whenever the charts are redrawn or the map changes to reflect time passing).